# Hidden Markov Model Tools : Jahmm

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-models

I am a novice to machine learning, I have read about the HMM but I still have a few questions:

1. When applying the HMM for machine learning, how can the initial, emmission and transition probabilities be obtained?
2. Currently I have a set of values (consisting the angles of a hand which I would like to classify via an HMM), what should my first step be?

   - I know that there are three problems in a HMM (ForwardBackward, Baum-Welch, and Viterbi), but what should I do with my data?
3. In the literature that I have read, I never encountered the use of distribution functions within an HMM, yet the constructor that JaHMM uses for an HMM consists of:

   - number of states
   - Probability Distribution Function factory
   - Constructor Description:
     Creates a new HMM. Each state has the same pi value and the transition probabilities are all equal.
     Parameters:
     nbStates The (strictly positive) number of states of the HMM.
     opdfFactory A pdf generator that is used to build the pdfs associated to each state.

What is this used for? And how can I use it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have to somehow model and learn the initial, emmision, and tranisition probabilities such that they represent your data.
In the case of discrete distributions and not to much variables/states you can obtain them form maximum likelihood fitting or you train a discriminative classifier that can give you a probability estimate like Random Forests or Naive Bayes. For continuous distributions have a look at Gaussian Processes or any other regression method like Gaussian Mixture Models or Regression Forests.

Regarding your 2. and 3. question: they are to general and fuzzy to be answered here. You should kindly refer to the following books: "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" by Bishop and "Probabilistic Graphical Models" by Koller/Friedman.

Comment: thank you a lot for your information my friend! I will get to it immediately and accept your answer once I digest all this information :)